# Pipewire alternative to `pactl load-module module-native-protocol-tcp`

Tags: pulseaudio, pipewire

To separate work and play I have two accounts on my Ubuntu laptop.  "jk" and "jkwork".  But there are times I want to run some software using the jkwork account without logging out and back in.  To do this, I create a port for pulseaudio to connect to, and ssh to the work account, creating an X-windows tunnel.

In particular, on my jk account I have a short script:

```
pactl load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-anonymous=1
ssh -R 22753:localhost:4713 -X jkwork@localhost
```

and on the jkwork account I have a one-line script:

```
export PULSE_SERVER="tcp:localhost:22753"
```

and I have modified my pulseaudio `default.pa` to allow for local sound connections by TCP

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.0.0/24
```

With this, I can, for example, watch a video that is stored on the work account with sound.

However pulseaudio is being replaced by pipewire in ubuntu.

What should I do to create the same connection in pipewire?

Comment: For the time being (pipewire 0.3.64 on archlinux here) the pulseaudio commands work seamlessly, i.e. `pactl load-module module-native-protocol-tcp ...` etc.

Comment: Is that something guarenteed by the pipewire folks?  That pactl and friends will continue to work "as expected", or am I using a depreciated interface.